# How to use Redis mass insertion?

Tags: redis

I've read [mass-insert](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) provided at redis.io, but it really confused me. I tried to make a file then use "cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe" to insert:

```
    SET Key0 Value0
    SET Key1 Value1
    SET Key2 Value3
```

Then I got this:

```
    All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
    ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
    ERR unknown command '$4'
    ERR wrong number of arguments for 'echo' command
    ERR unknown command '$20'
```

I also tried

```
    *3<cr><lf>
    $3<cr><lf>
    SET<cr><lf>
    $3<cr><lf>
    key<cr><lf>
    $5<cr><lf>
    value<cr><lf>
```

Then I got this: ERR Protocol error: invalid multi bulk length

It really make me confused. Can anyone give me a simple example? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Here it is:

```
echo -n '*3\r\n$3\r\nset\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n' | ./redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 1
```

Your problem probably comes from the cr+lf separators. You can use the hexdump -C command to check this point:

```
echo -n '*3\r\n$3\r\nset\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n' | hexdump -C
00000000  2a 33 0d 0a 24 33 0d 0a  73 65 74 0d 0a 24 33 0d  |*3..$3..set..$3.|
00000010  0a 6b 65 79 0a 0d 24 35  0d 0a 76 61 6c 75 65 0d  |.key..$5..value.|
00000020  0a                                                |.|
00000021
```

Also, you may want to check your target is a recent Redis instance and not a pre-1-2 version (which does not support the "[unified protocol](http://redis.io/topics/protocol)").

**Note:** the above lines works fine with zsh. If you use bash, you need to add a $ before the quote to trigger ANSI-C quoting:

```
echo -n $'*3\r\n$3\r\nset\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n' | hexdump -C
```

Comment: I use 2.4.14 version. It support the protocol. And I got this: $ echo -n '*3\r\n$3\r\nset\r\n$3\r\nkey\n\r$5\r\nvalue\r\n' | ./src/redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
ERR Protocol error: invalid multibulk length

Comment: For hexdump -C, I got "|*3\r\n$3\r\nset\|", not |*3..$3..set..$3.|.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So it means \r\n is not correctly interpreted by your shell - do you use bash or another shell? I use zsh to get this output.

Comment: I'm using a Macbook. It's bash.

Comment: No, you just need to find how to generate the proper sequence of characters with the OSX shell (i.e. cr+lf = 0d0a in hex)

Comment: Seems with bash you just have to add a $ before a ' to get the proper backslash exansion. echo -n $'*3\r\n$3\r\nset\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n' | hexdump -C

Comment: Add '$' in front of the string works. And I've changed my shell to zsh. This command also works: echo -n '*...\n' | ./redis-cli --pipe. But I still can't use "cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe" to feed redis with local file. +_+

Comment: Well I guess it certainly works if you launch echo -n '*...\n' > data.txt ; cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
echo -e "$(cat data.txt)" | redis-cli --pipe
```

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to work with the `SET Key0 Value0` form.

Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30511742/2613942

The reply is about the `LPUSH` command. It also works fine with `SET`.

To summarize, double-quote the parameters

```
SET "mykey" "myval"
```

Change the format of the file from unix to windows with `unix2dos`:

```
unix2dos myfile.txt
```

Then import using

`cat myfile.txt | src/redis-cli --pipe`

That worked for me.