# redis - mass inserts and counters

Tags: redis

This is my first question here on stackoverflow.
Dear community, thanks a lot for your combined knowledge and expertise !

I'm new to Redis so please bear with me, as I'm sure there is a simple solution.

```
redis-server --version
```

=> Redis server v=2.6.14 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64

```
redis-cli --version
```

=> redis-cli 2.6.14

I have read "How to use Redis mass insertion?"
[How to use Redis mass insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195341/how-to-use-redis-mass-insertion) 
 
I have googled and read a lot of praise for the redis INCR feature. But I don't really understand everything and it does not help me to do this redis-internally only.

My goal:
I want to import 'n' lines of text into redis and retrive them later in exactly this order.

For each line I set a unique key, like key:1, key:2, key:3 etc.
By using an increasing counter as part of the key I am able to later retrieve the lines in the same order in which they were stored in redis.

---

Now (without redis mass insert) I solve this easily 
by using an awk script to generate redis-cli calls, like:

```
cat data.txt | awk -f myscript.awk | bash
```

---

"data.txt" looks like this:
This is the first line.
This here is the much longer second line.

---

"myscript.awk" looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

### This section is being applied before any line is read:
BEGIN {
# Set counter initially to Zero
print "redis-cli SET counter 0"
}

### This section is being applied per line read into awk:
{
# Increase counter by One
print "redis-cli INCR counter"
# Read current counter from redis into an variable
print "MYCOUNTER=`redis-cli GET counter`"
# Use this variable as counter for the key
print "redis-cli SET key:$MYCOUNTER \"" $0 "\""
# Retrive stored value from redis for illustration
print "redis-cli GET key:$MYCOUNTER"
}
```

The output of "cat data.txt | awk -f myscript.awk | bash" is:

```
OK
(integer) 1
OK
"This is the first line."
(integer) 2
OK
"This here is the much longer second line."
```

So everything is fine.

---

But instead of calling "redis-cli" twice per imported line 
I want to use the redis "mass insert" feature. Here I need your help:

How would I do something like this in redis only ?

```
SET counter 0
=> OK
INCR counter
=> (integer) 1
GET counter
=> "1"
SET KEY:{counter} "Content of line 1"
=> OK
INCR counter
=> (integer) 2
GET counter
=> "2"
SET KEY:{counter} "Different content of line 2"
=> OK
```

etc., etc.

The "GET counter" lines are just for illustration.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks again !

bernie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list for this. There's no reason to use a new key for each line. All the list commands are [here](http://redis.io/commands#list), but the one you want is [RPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/rpush). You can rpush many values at once in the same line, so you'll just do that:

```
RPUSH some_key line1 line2 ... lineN
```

Then to retrieve:

```
LRANGE some_key 0 -1
```

Quick and easy!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer!
Works like a charm :-) I had tinkered a bit with hashes 
but the list elements were returned in a random sequence.

LRANGE returns the elements in exactly the sequence they were stored with RPUSH. Nifty!
@Eli

Comment: Oops, mistake in my comment. Sorry!
I have tried "SADD" and "SMEMBERS" without success.  
"SMEMBERS" returned results in a random sequence.

My pleasure to close my question due to Eli's answer

@Eli