# Redis Mass Insertion HSET command

Tags: java, shell, redis, pipelining

I have been looking all over SO for a working solution but no luck :/

I want to perform the mass insertion using the `pipelining` feature of `redis-cli` but I am not able to do so.

I have a JAVA code snippet which create a file containing all the commands to run.

```
      String add = "*4\r\n$4\r\nHSET\r\n$22\r\ndiscountProgramOffers\r\n$" +
            key.getBytes().length + "\r\n" + key + "\r\n$" +
            json.getBytes().length + "\r\n" + json + "\r\n";

            System.out.println(add);
```

In the above code, I followed [mass insertion link](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) present at Redis Documentation site.

And this is a demo String which is getting created.

`*4\r\n$4\r\nHSET\r\n$22\r\ndiscountProgramOffers\r\n$5\r\nmykey\r\n$7\r\nmyvalue\r\n`

When I run the file which is created by the snippet, sometimes I get nothing, and sometimes I get this error:

```
Error writing to the server: Connection reset by peer
```

**EX:**

```
echo -e "$(cat  massInsert.txt)" | redis/src/redis-cli --pipe
Error writing to the server: Connection reset by peer
```

Am I doing something wrong??
Please help.

FYI: I referred to these questions:

1. [Redis Mass Insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870623/redis-mass-insertion)
2. [redis - mass inserts and counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345242/redis-mass-inserts-and-counters)

Comment: Please specify reason and be courteous to others when you are going to downvote :)

Comment: You don't use a redis client library? Like Jedis?

Comment: I tried jedis, but the pipelining is not that efficient as it goes like a single command at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple off-by-one error in creating the RESP protocol string:) There are 21, not 22 characters in the `discountProgramOffers` hash name.

It worked for me (also with `printf` instead of `echo -e`), but only in Alpine's shell `ash` (see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74531227/9962007) for details):

```bash
# inspect data
$ cat redis-cmd-tst.txt 
*4\r\n$4\r\nHSET\r\n$21\r\ndiscountProgramOffers\r\n$5\r\nmykey\r\n$7\r\nmyvalue\r\n

# transfer
$ echo -e $(cat redis-cmd-tst.txt) | redis-cli --pipe -a $REDIS_PASSWORD
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 1

# verify
$ redis-cli -a $REDIS_PASSWORD hget discountProgramOffers mykey
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
"myvalue"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing everything right, but it still does not work, it may be your linux shell's fault and you may need to **switch the shell** (e.g. to `BusyBox` `ash` on Alpine, where Redis is usually conveniently installed, at least in containerized versions).

Correctly formed RESP strings should display in full (i.e. with each keyword and key or value name in separate line) when using either of these commands:

```
$ printf $(cat redis-cmd-tst.txt)
*1
$4
HSET
$21
discountProgramOffers
$6
mykey1
$8
myvalue1

$ echo -e $(cat /tmp/tst/redis-cmd-tst.txt)
*1
$4
HSET
$21
discountProgramOffers
$6
mykey1
$8
myvalue1
```

Currently I've verified it works either in BusyBox `ash` (linked to `/bin/sh`) on Alpine:

```
$ echo $0
/bin/ash

$ /bin/ash --help
BusyBox v1.35.0 (2022-08-01 15:14:44 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: ash [-il] [-|+Cabefmnuvx] [-|+o OPT]... [-c 'SCRIPT' [ARG0 ARGS] | FILE ARGS | -s ARGS]

Unix shell interpreter

$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.16.2
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.16"
```

... while it fails to print correctly RESP files in either shell preinstalled on Ubuntu (so both in `bash` and in `dash`, to which `sh` is linked on Ubuntu):

```
$ printf $(cat dict-to-redis-working.txt)
$ echo -e $(cat dict-to-redis-working.txt)
 31T3

$ echo $0
/bin/dash

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```