# redis bulk import using --pipe

Tags: redis

I'm trying to import one million lines of redis commands, using the `--pipe` feature.

**redis_version:2.8.1**

`cat file.txt | redis-cli --pipe`

This results in the following error:

Error reading from the server: Connection reset by peer

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

`file.txt` contains, for example,

```
lpush name joe
lpush name bob
```

**edit**: I now see there's probably a special format(?) for using pipe mode - http://redis.io/topics/protocol

Comment: were u able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Nik nope! still researching...

Comment: Did you find the answer?? I am looking for HSET command but even the documentation says nothing :O

Comment: @ADi you need for format the file into certain syntax. they show it in the documentation but i've never done it.

Comment: @d-_-b: thanks for the reply. I am there. The error processing is really bad in Redis.I just hope they improve it. Can't figure out what's happening :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use the pipe mode (a.k.a [bulk loading, or mass insertion](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/bulk-loading/)) you must indeed provide your commands directly in [Redis protocol](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) format.

The corresponding Redis protocol for `LPUSH name joe` is:

```
*3
$5
LPUSH
$4
name
$3
joe
```

Or as a quoted string: `"*3\r\n$5\r\nLPUSH\r\n$4\r\nname\r\n$3\r\njoe\r\n"`.

This is what your input file must contain.

[Redis documentation](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/bulk-loading/) includes a **Ruby sample** to help you generate the protocol: see `gen_redis_proto`.

A **Python sample** is available e.g. in the [redis-tools](https://github.com/salimane/redis-tools) package.

Answer (score 15):

The first point is that the parameters have to be double-quoted. The documentation is somewhat misleading on this point.

So a working syntax is :

```
lpush "name" "joe"
lpush "name" "bob"
```

The second point is that each line has to end by an `\r\n` and not just by `\n`. To fix that point, you just have to convert your file with the command `unix2dos`

like : `unix2dos file.txt`

Then you can import your file using `cat file.txt | src/redis-cli --pipe`

This worked for me.

Comment: On linux you can use tofrodos and the todos command to achieve this. Worked for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: your answer helped. thanks
awk could do pretty much of job...
`cat file.txt | awk '{print "SET","\""$1"\"","\""$2"\""}' |awk '{printf "%s\r\n", $0}' |redis-cli --pipe`

Answer (score 1):

There are existing tools that convert client commands directly to redis wire protocol messages. Example:

redis-mass my-client-script.txt | redis-cli --pipe option

https://golanglibs.com/dig_in/redis-mass
https://github.com/almeida/redis-mass

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of possibilities.

First check point is exceed of maxclients limits.

You can check using 'info clients' and 'config get maxclients' redis command.

In my desktop result is below.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info clients
# Clients
connected_clients:2
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0
127.0.0.1:6379> config get maxclients
1) "maxclients"
2) "2"
```

and then i tried to use pipe command, below is result.

```
[localhost redis-2.8.1]$ cat test.txt | ./src/redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Error reading from the server: Connection reset by peer
```

If that result is same. you have to change redis.conf file.

Seconds check point is ulimit option.

ulimit option change needs a root privilige. check below link.

[How do I change the number of open files limit in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-open-files-limit-in-linux)

Answer (score -1):

This error happens because the timeout set in Redis is Default, 0. You need to configure this timeout value by redis-cli using the command below:

To connect in redis server:
redis-cli -h  -p  -a

To view timeout value configured:
this command-line: **config get timemout**, Works to see what is the timeout value was configured in Redis server.

To Set new value for redis timeout:
this command-line: **config set timeout 120**, Set the timeout to 2 minutes. So, you need to set the redis timeout so long your execution need.

I hope this answers help you. Cyu!!!

Comment: Would this help if the error is write-based instead of read-based (as in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963829/redis-zadd-throws-redis-exceptionsconnectionerror-error-104-while-writing-to)

Comment: I deleted the question, solved it in another way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Nope, zero is infinity here (`redis-cli --help` on `--pipe-timeout` says: `Use 0 to wait forever`)

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following command to import your file's data to redis

```
cat file.txt | xargs  -L1 redis-cli
```

Comment: Hi, my question is specific to the bulk import using `--pipe`.