# Select all key data for a specific pattern from Redis using PHP

Tags: php, redis, key, keystore, host

I am using [PHPRedis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) for this.

I need to create script that copies all of the keys with the pattern `mobile*` from one Redis **host1** to **host2**.

I have got this working by selecting all keys from **host1** with the pattern `mobile*`. Then looping over each of these keys using the `get` key method to return the data. I then set the key for **host2** using the `set` method:

```
$auKeys = $redis->keys("mobile*");
foreach ($auKeys as $key) {
    $data = $redis->get($key);
    $redis2->set($key, $data, 6000);
    echo $key;
}
```

The problem is this takes around 5 minutes - I need to get it down to 2-3 minutes. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: How much of that time is spent running KEYS ?

Comment: Fetching the keys is instant - a few seconds, Looping each key takes several minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest route to `SET` you can take for a better performance is to `PIPE` the keys and hit the redis server once to execute all of them instead of a trip/key .

https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/251

```
$pipeline = $redis->multi($host, Redis::PIPELINE);

//put result in our shared list
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $pipeline->sAdd($key, $item);
}

$ret = $pipeline->exec();
```

At the same time, there is also libraries out there if you are seeking a different way to trasnlate commands to [Redis Protocol](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) .

[redis bulk import using --pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864505/redis-bulk-import-using-pipe)

Comment: Thanks Rabee, this seems to have fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, it's best to avoid KEYS in production code. It's preferable to modify the application that's writing the keys yo keep a list of keys in use, where possible, or use the newer SCAN operation.

In this case you revealed that KEYS wasn't taking a long time (it will when you have a very large key space, will the number of keys grow with time?), so the slow performance is due to all the network roundtrips. One per GET.  Pipelines are indeed a great way of grouping up operations to avoid roundtrips.

In this case I suggest the use of MGET to get all the values in one network op and MSET to update them in one network op.