# Unable to write to Redis using the protocol specification

Tags: bash, nosql, redis

When I telnet in to my Redis server on port 6379 I should be able to use the Protocol Specification outlined in http://redis.io/topics/protocol.  Instead I get invalid bulk length.  Anything I put after the initial *3(that starts the protocol spec) throws back this error.
I am using Bash on Suse Linux Enterprise 11.

For example:

```
telnet localhost 6379
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
*3\r\n$5\r\nLPUSH\r\n$4\r\nlogs\r\n$20\r\n"this is some data!"\r\n
-ERR Protocol error: invalid multibulk length
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

as well as even:

```
telnet localhost 6379
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
*3\r\n
-ERR Protocol error: invalid multibulk length
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I am on Redis 2.6(Redis server v=2.6.13) that should support the protocol spec.
What could I be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance,
Cole

Answer (score 1):

The \r\n are not interpreted by telnet. They stands for carriage return and linefeed, and they are just part of the telnet protocol. Just press "Enter" to generate them from telnet.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 6379
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
*3
$5
LPUSH
$4
logs
$20
"this is some data!"
:1
quit
+OK
```

I would recommend to use any Perl/Python/Ruby/PHP/... script to access Redis rather than having to deal with the Redis protocol directly from a shell script.

Comment: It didnt occur to me that carriage return and linefeed where already built in to Telnet.  What I am really trying to do is pipe it in through port 6379 and in this case using syslog-ng to write to that port.  I also tried doing something like    echo "*3\r\n$5\r\nLPUSH\r\n$4\r\nlogs\r\n$17\r\nthis is some data\r\n" | redis-cli --pipe           within bash and it results in the same error.  I guess my next question would be how to stream carriage return and linefeed inline to redis.

Comment: For syslog-ng, I guess it interprets \r\n fine - see http://benwilber.net/realtime-pixel-tracking-nginx-syslog-ng-redis

Comment: For redis-cli --pipe, it all depends on your shell. With bash you are supposed to write echo -n $'hello\r\nhello\r\n' to correctly expand the characters - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195341/how-to-use-redis-mass-insertion/13195609#13195609